How to create React Component dynamically and append to another DOM element
I'm a little new to React and I'm trying to create a React Component dynamically within my code and append it to a DOM element (outside of my render() function). I also want its ref so that I can call a function of this custom component. The main issue that I'm facing is that I can't use the React render() because I really want to use a query a DOM element (like document.querySelector('.grid')) and use it as the target to render my React custom component with React 18.
I tried using the code below with createElement() but that doesn't provide a ref to the component and I also don't think I can use it to append to another DOM element.
const myProps = { title: 'My Title' };
const elm = React.createElement(MyCustomComponent, myProps);

then I tried with createRef() with this following code
const paginationRef = createRef();
const MyComp = forwardRef(() => React.createElement(MyCustomComponent, { ref: paginationRef }));

but since I am not calling into the render(), it doesn't seem to fill the ref.
Here's a quick example of roughly how I'm trying to use it. Again, I know I could do it via the render() but that is not what I want to do, I really want to do it via any functions dynamically. Ideally I would like to move the loadComponentDynamically() function into a separate util service or function for reusability since I plan to use it this in a few other areas.
import { MyCustomPagination } from './MyCustomPagination';

export class GridComponent extends React.Component {
  loadComponentDynamically() {
    const myProps = { pageSize: 50, totalRows: 5000 };
    const elm = React.createElement(MyCustomPagination, myProps);
    
    // ... what else do I need?
    // I want to append the custom component to gridElm
    const gridElm = document.querySelector('.grid');
  }

  render() {
    // I DO NOT WANT TO USE IT HERE
    return (
     <div class="grid">...</div>
    );
  }
}

I'm easily able to do this with Angular via this simple code
export class AngularUtilService {
  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) { }

  createAngularComponent(component, targetElement) {
    // Create a component reference from the component
    const componentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(component, createCompOptions);

    // Get DOM element from component
    let domElem: HTMLElement | null = null;
    const viewRef = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>);

    // get DOM element from the new dynamic Component, make sure this is read after any data and detectChanges()
    if (viewRef && Array.isArray(viewRef.rootNodes) && viewRef.rootNodes[0]) {
      domElem = viewRef.rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

      // when user provides the DOM element target, we will read the new Component html and use it to replace the target html
      if (targetElement && domElem) {
        targetElement.innerHTML = domElem.innerHTML;
      }
    }

    return { componentRef, domElement };
  }

so if I'm able to do this in Angular, I'm assuming that there has to be a way to do it in React? I really have to do it on the fly and target a DOM element selector. I know I can do it inside a render() function but again that is not what I'm trying to do here, it really has to be a DOM query selector.
EDIT
It looks like I might have found a partial way to do it, I'm not sure if this is the correct approach? For example, I used the queueMicrotask to wait a cycle, but can I trust that a cycle will always be enough for my component to be rendered and ready?
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { MyCustomPagination } from './MyCustomPagination';

export class GridComponent extends React.Component {
  loadComponentDynamically(customComponent: any, targetContainer: HTMLElement) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const compRef = createRef();
      const root = createRoot(targetContainer);
      root.render(React.createElement(customComponent, { ref: paginationRef }));
      queueMicrotask(() => {
        resolve(paginationRef.current);
      });
    });
  }
}

then later, I can also call root.unmount() to dispose of the Component.
Side note, I know this is an anti-pattern in React, but it still is the best approach for my use case because the library that I support is a wrapper of a JavaScript library, so there are certain things that needs to be done in a native approach like this question.

It doesn't sound like you want to use React at all, just use a standard class or function. The defining characteristic of a React component is the render() method, without that it's not a component.

no, the point is that I created a component library that is a wrapper of a JavaScript library, so there are things that I need to do in native code.

That's fine, but if you want a component, it needs to have a render() method, ideally returning what you'll eventually imperatively manipulate. If you don't want that, and want to return no markup, what you're looking for is a custom hook, not a component.

ah yes sure my external Custom Component does have a render() function, the approach (the later Edit that I've made) seems to work, so I'll go ahead with this implementation

I really wouldn't recommend it, create a hook instead, this isn't what components are for.

interesting, if it allows loading this hook dynamically to a DOM element target via a query selector, then I would surely accept an answer on this subject. For my use case, it really has to be appended to DOM element of my choosing (query selector). Thanks

React Components are pieces of the UI that have their own internal state and appearance; what you're after, a building block of logic that provides no UI itself, is not a component.
This is where hooks come in, though it's important to note they cannot be used in classes, which you seem to be using for unknown reasons (they're been deprecated for years and do not work with newer React features).
Custom hooks allow you to reuse logic easily. An example for what you're doing:
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

function useGridComponent(CustomComponent, targetContainer) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const initialized = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized.current) return;
    initialized.current = true;
    createRoot(targetContainer).render(<CustomComponent ref={ref} />);

    // This cleans up your component -- how you should do so depends on
    // the exact situation, maybe clearing out the container like this is
    // fine, maybe you want to just delete some child nodes, etc. Something
    // for you to decide.
    return () => targetContainer.innerHTML = '';
  }, []);

  return ref;
}

// -------
//  Usage
// -------

const HelloWorld = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <h1 ref={ref}>HelloWorld</h1>;
})

function App() {
  const gridRef = useGridComponent(HelloWorld, document.getElementById('...'));
}

